# ResourceBundle en JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

He intentado de mil maneras hacer que el `ResourceBundle` obtenga los properties, en Java lo consigo sin problemas pero cuando lo intento en JavaFX es el problema.

aqui el error

`Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name strings, locale es_ES`

aqui el codigo

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var javaVersion = SystemInfo.javaVersion();
        var javafxVersion = SystemInfo.javafxVersion();

        ResourceBundle res;
        res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings");

        var label = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(label), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Aqui la imagen de como esta comformado el proyecto, el properties esta en la carpeta src.

[image: el properties esta en el src]

lo he probado exactamente igual en Java y me funciona, alguien conoce la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que al estar trabajando con Maven todos los archivos cuya extensión sea diferente a `.java` deben estar ubicados en la carpeta de recursos `src/main/resources`. De lo contrario, como es tu caso, todos estos archivos de recursos NO serán procesados y por ende tampoco se copiarán a la carpeta `target/classes`.

Este es el motivo por el que no se encuentran tus recursos de idioma. Para solucionarlo crea un directorio `resources` dentro de `src/main` y mueve tu archivo `strings.properties` a este nuevo directorio.